# CORS policy Issue, It works in local development, but it didn't work in deployed site

Tags: javascript, typescript, cors, nodes, sendgrid

I'm having trouble with the CORS policy problem.
The project is very simple. I'm using the Sendgrid for sending e-mail.
I implemented frontend and backend for this tiny project. In backend, Sendgrid sending mail function is used.

I tested in local, it works fine. After I deployed the project, I got CORS issue.
This is the Error messages.

1. Access to fetch at 'https://mailsender-api.xxxxxx.xxx/sendmail' from origin 'https://mailsender-xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
2. POST https://mailsender-api.xxxxxx.xxx/sendmail net::ERR_FAILED

In frontend I separate fetch function

```
Fetch.tsx

export const fetchPost = async ({ endpoint, data }: any) => {
  return fetch(`https://mailsender-api.xxxxxx.xxx/${endpoint}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    mode: "cors",
  });
};
```

and different file calls the fetch function

```
const handleClick = async (
    email: string,
    subject: string,
    intention: string
  ) => {
    if (email === "" || intention === "") {
      alert("Please fill out all fields");
    } else if (!validateEmail(email)) {
      alert("Invalid Email address");
    } else {
      const fetchOption = {
        endpoint: `sendmail`,
        data: {
          email,
          subject,
          intention,
        },
      };
      const result = await fetchPost(fetchOption);
      if (result.ok) {
        return history.push("/complete");
      }
    }
}
```

Below are backend code. I separate send mail function.

```
server.js

import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import { sendmail } from "./sendmail";
const router = express.Router();

const server = express();
server.use(
  cors({
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Accept"],
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  })
);
server.use(express.json({ type: ["application/json"] })); // for parsing application/json
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

router.post("/sendmail", sendmail);
router.options("*", cors());

server.use(router);

server.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log("app is listening");
});
export { router };
export default server;
```

when post requests comes in, sendmail function is invoked.

```
sendmail.js

import { sendScheduledMail } from "./config";

export const sendmail = async (req, res) => {
  let data = {
    address: req.body.email,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    content: req.body.intention,
  };
  try {
    await sendScheduledMail(data.address, data.subject, data.content);

    return res.end();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Below is config.js file

```
import sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import "../.env";

dotenv.config();

export const sendScheduledMail = (address, subject, content) => {
  let date = Math.round(new Date("June 29, 2020 12:37:00").getTime() / 1000);
  let tempDate = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  const email = {
    from: "CBLM@CBLM.com",
    to: address,
    subject: subject,
    html: `<p>${content}</p>`,
    send_at: tempDate,
  };

  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  return sgMail.send(email);
};
```

I deployed in Vercel.com. I asked about this problem, they said, it is codebase problem, so they have nothing to do. I searched for the solution, and I followed all they suggest, but it didn't work. Please help me.

------------------------UPDATED----------------------------------------

I deleted "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", but it is not working.
I found out that Vercel has their own configure file ('now.json'). I added some headers, then I got something else.

```
now.json file

{
"routes": [
    {
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://mailsender-delta.xxxxxx.xxx",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS, HEAD",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
      },
      "src": "/.*",
      "dest": "/server.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

I got POST https://mailsender-api.xxxxxx.xxx/sendmail net::ERR_ABORTED 405

Below is the request header

```
> General
Request URL: https://mailsender-api.xxxxxx.xxx/sendmail
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 
Remote Address: 76.76.21.21:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
> Response Headers
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: s-maxage=0
date: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 23:20:50 GMT
server: Vercel
status: 204
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-vercel-cache: HIT
x-vercel-id: iad1::frndf-1593818450293-40ef1caa15b3
> Request Header
:authority: mailsender-api.xxxxxx.xxx
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /sendmail
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ko;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
access-control-request-headers: access-control-allow-credentials,access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,content-type
access-control-request-method: POST
origin: https://mailsender-delta.vercel.app
referer: https://mailsender-delta.vercel.app/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
```

```
> General
Request URL: https://mailsender-api.xxxxxx.xxx/sendmail
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 
Remote Address: 76.76.21.21:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
> Response Headers
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: POST, OPTIONS, HEAD
access-control-allow-origin: https://mailsender-delta.vercel.app
cache-control: s-maxage=0
content-type: application/json
date: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 23:20:50 GMT
server: Vercel
status: 405
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-vercel-cache: HIT
x-vercel-id: iad1::frndf-1593818450309-4f5547ab5464
> Request Headers
:authority: mailsender-api.xxxxxx.xxx
:method: POST
:path: /sendmail
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ko;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
access-control-allow-methods: *
content-length: 88
content-type: application/json
origin: https://mailsender-delta.xxxxxx.xxx
referer: https://mailsender-delta.xxxxxx.xxx/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Use your back end as a proxy ... send fetch() to your server and it makes post to the api. Setting up CORS on your server has no effect on fetch() requests made directly to a third party

Comment: Is it possible that in production your node.js server is behind a proxy, load balancer or CDN? Sometimes these software intercept CORS calls and don't forward them.

Comment: I also don't think you should set `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",` on the client-side. Might cause issues.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, check your network tab and find the `OPTIONS` request. Share the full HTTP response here (all headers, status, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I deployed to Heroku and I solved the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The solution is available in the doc of vercel: https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors .
In your node.js backend, create a file vercel.json and put the code there.

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It works for sure.